# How to only use certain data in a geoJson file (with d3)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

For a project, I need to project a visualization onto a map of New York City, with a different feature for each community in the city.

My professor only wants us to map specific community districts however, without just simply deleting them from the file. The general format of the file is:

**{ "type": "FeatureCollection",                                                                   "features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 0, "properties": { "communityDistrict": 101,**  with the specific coordinate data following, and id and communityDistrict incrementing up for each feature. I'm looking to sort by "communityDistrict".

Here is a snippet of the code I have currently. All this should do is print a map of NYC.

```
function createMap(data, divId, projection, w, h) {
  //Create SVG element
  var mapSvg = d3.select(divId).append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);

  var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection);

  mapSvg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("fill", "none");
}

function createVis(data)
{
    mapData = data[0];
    stationData = data[1];

  var w = 800;
  var h = 400;

  var projection1 = d3.geoAlbersUsa()
    .fitSize([w,h], data[0]);
  createMap(data[0], "#map1", projection1, w, h);
}

// this loads the data and calls the createVis function
Promise.all([d3.json("https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/dakoop/fb4d65af84db0ee3f2233e02cdeb1874/raw/9a819d894ff29f786b61b7c3d0fa18f84b244362/nyc-community-districts.geojson"), //this link is the geoJson data in question
    d3.csv("https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/dakoop/fb4d65af84db0ee3f2233e02cdeb1874/raw/bb31d4c41bda64891455a68741accdfef40aeef3/bikeStationData.json")]).then(createVis)
```

Any ideas as to the call I'd need to make to either remap the file to a new variable or somehow just ignore the districts I'm not gonna be interested in? I've come up pretty dry thus far, so even a finger in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @lucascaro I appreciate the feedback, I'll try to keep that in mind from now on! Hope my edit is an improvement.

Comment: which fields match?, there is no `id` with value >1000 in geojson file

Comment: I'm sorry rioV8, I don't think I understand your question, can you clarify?